# Default language set by default french

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I do have the following entry in config.yml

```
framework:
      translator: { fallback: de }
```

When I go to my index page. Chrome always tells me that the website is in french and want to translate. How can I get rid of it that it is in french?

I don't want to disable the function in chrome.

I can't see anything else in the config-files that would solve my problem.

Comment: I think Chrome looks at the content and determines the language, so I don't think you can override that.

Comment: But I don't have anything else in french!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have what @Elnur suggested it doesn't hurt to also try this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Language" content="{{ app.request.locale}}"/>
```

Then, again, read this [StackExchange question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5043/how-can-i-prevent-google-mistakenly-offering-to-translate-a-page)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `lang` attribute on the `html` tag:

```
<html lang="{{ app.request.locale }}">
```

Comment: This I have in the layout file.